# Django project cannot find webpack_loader

Tags: django, webpack

I'm trying to run this project https://github.com/v1k45/ponynote But I get an error when running the api. I run it with python 3.6 as the latest python will not run django 1.11.

```
$ python manage.py runserver
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x103b5b500>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 113, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 249, in raise_last_exception
    six.reraise(*_exception)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named webpack_loader
```

Any idea what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

the error mentions python 2.7. Turns out I had not set the python version correctly in pipenv. Solution

```
pipenv install -r requirements.txt --python 3.6.6
```